# MySQL: Month Range Join

Tags: mysql, join, range

I have two tables:

```
**users**
id  firstname   lastname    
1   John        Mathews
2   Scott       Mithchell
....
....
....


**publish**
id  userid      bookid      published
1   1       1       2013-01-16 14:12:10
1   2       1       2013-01-08 15:17:40
1   2       1       2013-01-10 14:18:10
....
....
....
```

I need to find records of each user for each Month (Jan, Feb, March.... etc.) on the basis of field **"published"**. if there is no data for that user for relevant month then it should display 0 (Zero). So the output should look like this:-

```
id  firstname   lastname    month       published
1   John        Mathews     January     1
1   John        Mathews     february    2
1   John        Mathews     march       1
1   John        Mathews     april       1
1   John        Mathews     may         1
1   John        Mathews     june        1
1   John        Mathews     july        0
1   John        Mathews     august      0
1   John        Mathews     september   0
1   John        Mathews     October     0
1   John        Mathews     November    0
1   John        Mathews     December    1
2   Scott       Mitchell    January     2
2   Scott       Mitchell    february    2
2   Scott       Mitchell    march       1
2   Scott       Mitchell    april       1
2   Scott       Mitchell    may         1
2   Scott       Mitchell    june        0
2   Scott       Mitchell    july        0
2   Scott       Mitchell    august      1
2   Scott       Mitchell    september   1
2   Scott       Mitchell    October     0
2   Scott       Mitchell    November    0
2   Scott       Mitchell    December    1
```

Answer (score 0):

** months **

```
nr | monthName
----------
1  | january
2  | february
...
```

Then:

```
SELECT p.id, fristname, lastname, m.monthName AS month, count(*) as published
FROM months m LEFT JOIN publish p ON MONTH(p.published) = m.nr
JOIN users u ON u.id = p.userid
GROUP BY p.id, firstname, lastname, month
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: I also need to include empty months in the same query.

Comment: Can we create Months range at run time instead of creating a separate table?

Comment: You can pivot the table, have 12 month columns, and a counter for each user per year. This will be ok?

Comment: Read on table pivoting for MySQL, this should be easy now : http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78